# Evaluate the Legendre's Symbol $\frac{2017}{5003}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I got 1, this is the way I approached this. Any suggestion to get the answer faster or less messy is appreciated.

$\frac{2017}{5003} = (-1)^{(2016)(5002)/4}(\frac{5003}{2017})$

= $\frac{969}{2017} = (-1)^{(968)(2016)/4}(\frac{2017}{969})$

= $\frac{79}{969} = (-1)^{(78)(968)/4}(\frac{969}{79})$

= $\frac{21}{79} = (-1)^{(20)(78)/4}(\frac{79}{21})$

= $\frac{16}{21} = (-1)^{(15)(20)/4}(\frac{21}{16})$

= $\frac{16}{21} \rightarrow \frac{4}{7} \times \frac{4}{3} \rightarrow \frac{2^2}{7} \times \frac{2^2}{4} \rightarrow 1 \times 1 =1.$

Comment: Easier, I think, to use reciprocity.  $\big ( \frac {2017}{5003}\big ) = \big ( \frac {5003}{2017}\big ) =\big( \frac {969}{2017}\big ) $ and so on.

Comment: but about the cases when it's not divisible by 4 thus making it negative?

Comment: I don't understand.  Since $969=3\times17\times 19$ you just have to compute three simple symbols.

Comment: Maybe you were using reciprocity...bit hard to tell.  Clearly $2017\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ so you can invert the fraction without changing the sign.

Comment: I thought the OP's calculation was using the Jacobi symbol in intermediate steps and the corresponding generalization of quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: Though in the last line, $\left( \frac{16}{21} \right) = \left( \frac{4}{7} \right) \left( \frac{4}{3} \right)$ is incorrect reasoning, at that point I would just use that 16 is obviously a square so $\left( \frac{16}{21} \right) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot all remainders are not primes, and the Legendre's symbol is multiplicative. Thus, since $969=3\cdot 17\cdot 19$, we have that
\begin{align}
\Bigl(\frac{969}{2017}\Bigr)&=\Bigl(\frac{3}{2017}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{17}{2017}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{19}{2017}\Bigr)=\Bigl(\frac{2017}{3}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{2017}{17}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{2017}{19}\Bigr) \\
&=\Bigl(\frac{1}{3}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{11}{17}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{3}{19}\Bigr)=\Bigl(\frac{11}{17}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{3}{19}\Bigr)\\
&=\Bigl(\frac{17}{11}\Bigr)\cdot (-1)\Bigl(\frac{19}{3}\Bigr)=-\Bigl(\frac{6}{11}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{1}{3}\Bigr)=-\Bigl(\frac{6}{11}\Bigr)=+1.
\end{align}